# Why is there space at end of method names ending with an operator?

Tags: scala

I've been learning Scala recently, and learned that for method names, if the method name ends in an operator symbol (such as defining unary_- for a class), and we specify the return type, we need a space between the final character of the method and the : which let's us specify the return type.

```
def unary_-: Rational = new Rational(-numer, denom)
```

The reasoning I have heard for this is that : is also a legal part of an identifier, so we need a way of separating the identifier and the end of the method name. But letters are legal parts of identifiers too, so why don't we need a space if we just have a method name that is all letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the [language spec (p. 12)](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) or [html](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html#identifiers):

> First, an identifier can start with a letter
>   which can be followed by an arbitrary sequence of letters and digits. This may be
>   followed by underscore ‘_’ characters and another string composed of either letters
>   and digits or of operator characters

That is, to include operator characters into identifiers, they must be joined with an underscore.

Looking at `def unary_-: Rational = new Rational(-numer, denom)`, with the underscore joining `unary` with `-:`, the colon is interpreted as part of the method name if there is no space. Therefore, with the colon being part of the method name, it can't find the colon precedes the return type.

```
scala> def test_-: Int = 1   // the method name is `test_-:`
<console>:1: error: '=' expected but identifier found.

scala> def test_- : Int = 1  // now the method name is `test_-`, and this is okay.
test_$minus: Int
```

If you want the colon to be part of the method name, it would have to look like this:

```
scala> def test_-: : Int = 1
test_$minus$colon: Int
```

Method names with just letters will not have this problem, because the colon isn't absorbed into the name following an underscore.